# cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1001 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

i'm using laravel framework. AWS SNS service was using and installed all requiremnets in my projects with the help of a link that is attached.

https://www.kerneldev.com/2018/01/03/send-sms-in-laravel-using-aws-sns/

but getting
cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1001 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

deleted old access key and secret key and added new one in aws console and changed keys in config/aws.php

Added all TXT and DKIM records in DNS setting

Created web route

```
Route::get('/sendSMS/{phone_number}', 'SMSController@sendSMS');
```

Created controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use AWS;

class SMSController extends Controller
{
    protected function sendSMS($phone_number){
        $sms = AWS::createClient('sns');

        $sms->publish([
                'Message' => 'Hello, This is just a test Message',
                'PhoneNumber' => $phone_number,
                'MessageAttributes' => [
                    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'  => [
                        'DataType'    => 'String',
                        'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
                     ]
                 ],
              ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to find a way to configure a longer timeout in the client creation process.

Comment: Are you sure you access keys are read correctly? Also is there anything that would block outwards communication with AWS from the server you're running this code on?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` with `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` in `CurlFactory.php.`

```
$conf[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = $options['timeout'] * 10000;
```

This is work for me,Try it.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for this error

> Increase your CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS timeout in CurlFactory.php

```
$timeoutRequiresNoSignal |= $options['timeout'] < 1;
$conf[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS] = $options['timeout'] * 10000;
```

try this

Comment: This is not a good answer. I still haven't solve this but it seems related to the URL being hit.